# Cryptic Crossword Clue - single clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

This is a single cryptic crossword clue. I like crosswords, but I am not good at the cryptic ones where several different part of the clue all lead to the same word. This is not a clue from a crossword, but rather a single clue I made up. *This paragraph is not part of the puzzle.*

> Small parent at lowest point [7]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least this may be

> MINIMUM → Small (MINI)  + parent (MUM) which by definition is at lowest point

Comment: Yes, good job... :-)

Comment: Tom, meet tom.  tom, Tom.

Comment: "At least" indeed.

Comment: Wait I thought you two were the same person...